# In R, how can I label/rename all variables in a column that begin with a particular letter/word?

Tags: r, sorting, columnsorting

I am trying to group certain products based on their brands. Even after cleaning the data, there are a large number of spelling/spacing errors under the product name. Which makes it hard to categorise into a brand. Can anyone please guide me here ? I would like to know how to create a function where I can use 'any word starting with or containing certain letters of the item ' and link that to 'brand'.

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMODs.png

Thankyou

UI

Comment: Please show an example of your current data and the expected output you want to achieve.

Comment: I hope this will shed some more light on my question, I do not want to share the exact data, as it may be confidential. But it is of a very similar format to the one shown in the link. The required output is 'Brand' column.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMODs.png

Comment: Hi, @Urb_Ink, welcome to stackoverflow. 
You may want to take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference on how to ask questions ans hsare the data.

Comment: @Urb_Ink, to elaborate a bit on Aramis7d's point. It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: A good idea is to `dput` part of your data. You can remove any sensitive information and only leave whatever is pertinent to your question. That said, you probably want to look at `grep` and evaluate using regex.

Comment: Considering the unpredictable nature of spelling errors, you might even want to work with string comparison measures, for example `vwr::levenshtein.distance()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question, but this should work:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(test = c("ABC", "BLA", "DRA", "ADC", "AFA" ,"APA", "ZBG", "AGL"))

data_new <- data %>% 
  mutate(test = if_else(substr(test,1,1) == "A", "AAA", as.character(test)))
```